# How to map 2 different methods from the same class to GET request in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I created a REST API in java with spring boot , but when I try to run it I get some error that it has already mapped one method from one of the controller classes to the get method and it can't map another one even though they have different names. Ex: `/drugs/filtered/{amount}` and `/drugs/report`
Here is the code

```java
    @RestController
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class DrugController {
           private DrugService service;
           private DrugConverter drugConverter;

    @RequestMapping(name = "/drugs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public DrugDTO handleAddDrug(@RequestBody DrugDTO dto) {
        Drug addedDrug = service.addDrug(
                dto.getId(),
                dto.getName(),
                dto.getRecommendedAmount());
        return drugConverter.convertModelToDto(addedDrug);
    }

    @RequestMapping(name = "/drugs", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public DrugDTO handleUpdateDrug(@RequestBody DrugDTO dto) {
        Drug updated = service.updateDrug(
                dto.getId(),
                dto.getName(),
                dto.getRecommendedAmount());
        return drugConverter.convertModelToDto(updated);
    }

    @RequestMapping(name = "/drugs/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public DrugDTO handleDeleteDrug(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Drug deletedDrug = service.deleteDrug(id);
        return drugConverter.convertModelToDto(deletedDrug);
    }

    @GetMapping(name = "/drugs/{id}")
    public DrugDTO handleGetDrug(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Drug drug = service.getDrug(id);
        return drugConverter.convertModelToDto(drug);
    }

    @GetMapping(name = "/drugs")
    public DrugsDTO handleGetAllDrugs() {
        Collection<Drug> drugs = service.getAllDrugs();
        return new DrugsDTO(drugs.stream().map(drugConverter::convertModelToDto).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }

    @GetMapping(name = "/drugs/filtered/{amount}")
    public DrugsDTO handleGetDrugsWithDoseBiggerThan(@PathVariable Integer amount) {
        Collection<Drug> drugs = service.getDrugsWithDoseBiggerThan(amount);
        return new DrugsDTO(drugs.stream().map(drugConverter::convertModelToDto).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }

    @GetMapping(name = "/drugs/report")
    public DrugsDTO handleGetDrugsWithDosesOf() {
        Collection<Drug> drugs = service.getDrugsWithDosesOf();
        return new DrugsDTO(drugs.stream().map(drugConverter::convertModelToDto).collect(Collectors.toSet()));

    }
}
```

And this is the error:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'drugController' method  BloodManagement.ServerSide.Controller.DrugController#handleGetDrug(Integer) to {GET []}: There is already 'drugController' bean method BloodManagement.ServerSide.Controller.DrugController#handleGetAllDrugs() mapped.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the parameter **name** to **value** on all your mapping.

i.e.:

```java
@GetMapping(name = "/drugs")
```

becomes

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/drugs")
```